# How to structure R projects

Tags: r

I love using R, but comparing it to the Python workflow, I have trouble getting something that feels as "stable".
My situation is:

- I have a git repository that hosts an R project and and `renv` environment.
- In this repository, I have multiple analyses that are intertwined to a certain extent.
- I would like to test most of the functionality and only call tested functions in a main analysis script.

I'm aware that the usual approach is an R package. With this, however, you can't have granular folder structure, since no subfolders are allowed in `R/`.
Splitting up the repository, I would end up with a myriad of small packages, dedicated R projects and `renv` environments, which doesn't seem correct given the partial interdependence, like helper functions I want to be accessible from everywhere.

Also, approaches like the `drake` or `target` packages are awesome for reproducibility, but seem to be geared towards single pipelines/analyses per R project.

Just `source`ing everything everywhere (as is shown in example workflows for these packages) is dangerous, given that I want small functions to break down functionality and enhance reusability, with more of these functions the likelihood of functions overwriting each other unnoticed increases. I could use a common prefix for functions in a file, but this might result in overly long names and less expressive code.

Testing with `testthat` is mostly intended for packages. I can use `test_dir`, but that needs to be clumsily launched from a shell script or something, no support in an IDE anymore to run single tests.

The `import` package solves alot of these issues. It gives you a file as a workspace, where you can define as many functions or constants as you want, and if you import a function from that file, the functions/imported functions within that file are accessible to the function, but not available from the outside. This gives very neat encapsulation, but this doesn't work for the `drake` or `target` packages which can't detect the nested dependencies of imported functions, which breaks their purpose.

So my question is: What do you recommend as an approach for setting up something *slightly* bigger? All guides out there on R are for very simple analysis setups only and don't really answer my question, they rarely deal with testability or predictable behaviour of your analysis.

Thanks alot in advance!

Michael

Comment: Why not create your own R package, that will make code extremely portable

Comment: @stevec I addressed that in my question quite in the beginning. Several parts of different analyes might have a function which might want to be named `preprocess` (or whatever), that would create clashes in a package, no? If so, how's that shielding me from weird behaviour compared to `source`? Also, I might have helper functions that are unique to an analysis, should I "nest" these by very long filenames since I can't create subfolders in `R` for each analysis? As stated, I don't want to maintain 10 packages with their own repositories(?), R projects and `renv`s, a nightmare to deploy too.